# List Items not clickable. Can't view items

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, list-form

I have 2 SharePoint lists. (List A) was created by importing Excel file, and the other one was created manually (List B).

We use both Lists to input and view data.

Whenever we create an item in List B, it allows us to click on the title thus letting us view the item.

But when we try to click on any item of List A its not clickable. It juts gets selected and We have to go to the top and click on "view item" option in the Items menu.

How to make the List A behave like List B?

Comment: Hi I did a test in my end, whether it is imported from excel or manually created, you can directly click to view the item. Do you have this issue with only one list?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint online list view, when you (single) click on SharePoint default **Title** column, it opens list form.

**Possible Solutions**:

1. Include/Show **Title** column in list view:

   Maybe you (or someone else) removed/hide this column from list view. If you include/show this column in list view, it should work for you. If you can't find the column with name **Title**, it means it is **renamed** to something else.
2. **Double click** on item:

   You can double click on list item row to open the list form.